# Generic REST/RPC API for Python (OpenCPU Equivalent)

Tags: python, rest, opencpu

A coworker and I are currently using [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/) to expose analytics we write in R to other applications via a REST API. There has been a need recently to leverage some python libraries in a similar manner. From the OpenCPU description:

> OpenCPU is a system for embedded scientific computing and reproducible research. The OpenCPU server provides a reliable and interoperable HTTP API for data analysis based on R. You can either use the public servers or host your own.

Basically we update an R library on the server and it automatically exposes the updated and new functions at REST endpoints. It takes care of marshalling the data from JSON to S3 and then back to JSON. There is no need to manually configure routes with OpenCPU.

My question then, assuming we are operating in a secure environment, is does an equivalent for python exist? I've tried searching but have had little luck thus far.

Thanks!

Comment: Very interesting.  I don't know of any such library, but will be interested to see if anyone else does.  I don't think it would be that difficult to write such a thing in Python, but the hosting/computing power behind it would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [IPython](http://ipython.org/)? I'm not sure about supporting library updates.